# Can't append structure to array property

Tags: ios, swift, struct

When I add non-empty location to `locations` property of `User`, this property remains nil.

```
public struct User: Printable {
    var name: String
    var locations: [LocationData] = []

    public var description: String {
        return "User: \(name), locations: \(locations)"
    }
}

public struct LocationData: Printable {
    var unixtime: NSTimeInterval
    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees
    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees

    var date: NSDate{
        return NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: unixtime)
    }

    public var description: String {
        return "LocationData: date: \(date), latitude: \(latitude), longitude: \(longitude)"
    }
}
```

This is how I add locations to user:

```
    for userText in usersArray{
        let userFieldsArray = userText.componentsSeparatedByString(("|"))

        let username = userFieldsArray[0]
        var user = users.filter{$0.name == username}.first

        if user == nil{

            user = User(name: username, locations: [])
            users.append(user!)

        }

        let unixtime = (userFieldsArray[1] as NSString).doubleValue
        let latitude = (userFieldsArray[2] as NSString).doubleValue
        let longitude = (userFieldsArray[3] as NSString).doubleValue

        let location = LocationData(unixtime: unixtime, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        user?.locations.append(location)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the usual confusion about value types versus reference types, coming from a Java or C++ background. When you assign the user's contents to the local variable `user`, then mutate that variable at the bottom of your sample, you're only modifying the local copy. Change User over to a `class` and all will work.

Stylistically, if you're using a force-unwrap earlier in the code, you should also use a force-unwrap at the bottom, because you wouldn't want that to fail silently.

Alternatively, keep it a struct but don't put `user` into `users` until it's fully mutated.

Comment: So, the only way, as I understand to assign array of locations?